# Why does rustc say mismatched types?

Tags: rust

When I try to compile this code:

```
use ignore::WalkBuilder;

fn main() {
    let walk_iter = WalkBuilder::new("./").hidden(false).build();

    let mut walk_paths: Vec<std::path::PathBuf> = Vec::new();

    for entry in walk_iter {
        let entry = entry.unwrap().into_path();
        walk_paths.append(entry);
    }
}
```

I get the error when appending the entry:

```
mismatches types, expected mutable reference &mut std::vec::Vec<std::path::PathBuf> found struct std::path::PathBuf
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message as given by the compiler in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::vec::Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) method appends the content of another vector into the current one:

> ```
> pub fn append(&mut self, other: &mut Vec<T>)
> ```
>
> Moves all the elements of `other` into `Self`, leaving `other` empty.

You are looking for [`std::vec::Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push):

> ```
> pub fn push(&mut self, value: T)
> ```
>
> Appends an element to the back of a collection.